# Iframe site windows authentication giving the pop up even though parent site authenticated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe, windows-authentication

I have designed a website to use windows authentication. Everything works as expected. But my recent task was to integrate another site into this site(I can't re-write the whole application into this). So i have followed to use an iframe. Now my child site also uses windows authentication. So When i hit the parent site it is asking for windows credentials and user validated. When i hit the child site on iframe, it is again giving me the pop up to enter the credentials, Is there a work around for this? Please help.

Note: Both these applications are hosted on the same server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the two sites are a different subdomains or domains. If they're just different subdomains on the same domain, you can set the sites to use a wildcard domain cookie, which will allow any subdomain on that domain to see the cookie and recognize authentication from the other. However, if they're on different domains, you're out of luck.

Comment: What if they are like:    xyz.daminname.com  and child site is like xyz.domainname.com/childsite  as a virtual directory? Do you think this wildcard cookie works? Meanwhile i give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: Yes. Paths don't matter. It's just dependent on the domain name as cookies are domain-bound.